# Get JSON from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a javascript function that sends JSON to my server:

```
$("#sendRoute").live('click', function(){            
  trackCoords_str = JSON.stringify(trackCoords);             
  final_time_m_str = JSON.stringify(final_time_m);                
  final_time_s_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(final_time_s_rounded);
  aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(aver_speed_km_h_rounded);
  total_km_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(total_km_rounded);
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://test.whirlware.biz/server/",               
  type: "POST",
  data: { 
    route : trackCoords_str,                 
    timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,               
    timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
    averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
    distance: total_km_rounded_str,
  },
  dataType: "json"
 });
});
```

And mix of PHP and JS code that receive and display my JSON data

```
<?php
$route = $_POST['route'];
$timeInMinutes=$_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$timeInSeconds=$_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$averageSpeed=$_POST['averageSpeed'];
$distance=$_POST['distance'];

$trackCoords = json_decode($route, false);
$total_km_rounded = json_decode($timeInMinutes, false);
$final_time_m = json_decode($timeInSeconds, false);
$final_time_s_rounded = json_decode($averageSpeed, false);
$aver_speed_km_h_rounded = json_decode($distance, false);

echo $trackCoords['coordsarray'];
echo $total_km_rounded;
echo $final_time_m;
echo $final_time_s_rounded;
echo $aver_speed_km_h_rounded;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var total_km_rounded = '<?php echo $total_km_rounded ?>';
document.write('Растояние: ' + total_km_rounded);
var final_time_m = '<?php echo $final_time_m ?>';
document.write('Растояние: ' + final_time_m);
var final_time_s_rounded = '<?php echo $final_time_s_rounded ?>';
document.write('Растояние: ' + final_time_s_rounded);
var aver_speed_km_h_rounded = '<?php echo $aver_speed_km_h_rounded ?>';
document.write('Растояние: ' + aver_speed_km_h_rounded);
</script>
```

But when I send JSON data my server don`t display it. Where did I make a mistake?  Maybe I can receive JSON another way?

Comment: The first thing is, the success function. Look the documentation. The location are wrong.

Comment: I know, thanks, mybe you know another reason that can cause problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `success: function(response) {alert('Success!');},` after the `data`, not inside the `data`

```
data: { 
 route : trackCoords_str,                 
timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,               
timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
distance: total_km_rounded_str   
},
success: function(response) {alert('Success!');},
```

Comment: I deleted success: function(response) {alert('Success!');}, it`s not a reason of problem

Comment: I didn't say, this is the answer, this one also caused the issues.!

Answer (score 0):

You should JSON.stringify an array like this([general convention](http://www.json.org/js.html)):

```
 //rough code
    data['trackCoords_str'] = trackCoords;             
    data['final_time_m_str'] =final_time_m;                
    data['final_time_s_rounded_str'] = final_time_s_rounded;
    data['aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str'] = aver_speed_km_h_rounded;
    data['total_km_rounded_str'] = total_km_rounded;
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://test.whirlware.biz/server/",               
      type: "POST",
      data:  JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(){ alert('success!'); },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(thrownError);
     });
    });
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn`t work, I changed variables in index.php too but no result.

Comment: can you echo the posted data from php back to this javascript with success() function?

Comment: I added 
success: function(){ 
  alert('success!');
   },
   error: function(){
  alert('error!');
   }
And when I send JSON it shows "error" so my JSON is not sent. What can be the reason?

Comment: please see the error with this after success::  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Comment: I got 2 errors: http://clip2net.com/s/6vn7Ri and http://clip2net.com/s/6vn8oE But I don`t know what Syntax error here, I send only numbers data

Comment: the second image has your error, only send data['trackCoords_str'] = trackCoords; and see what happens and debug it by adding more post datas. Its tough but cant debug it from here

Comment: I also tried to change dataType: "json" to "jsonp" but then I get error: Unexpected number

Comment: use json and also console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) before ajax. See if the data is a valid json or not

Comment: It`s strange but my app don`t stringify needed data, maybe reaon of error is "Unexpected token ." I neede to delete "." somewhere?

Comment: if trackCoords or final_time_m are double cast it to string before JSON.stringify and see what happens,just a suggestion

Comment: I made total_km_rounded = total_km_rounded.toString(); for all variables but the error still shows

Comment: I converted all my nubers to fixed without "." and "Unexpected token ." error has vanished, but now error "Unexpected token <" apperears, I don`t have any "<" symbols in my variables, what can it be?